# Why is my Unity IOS App crashing after uploading it to Xcode?

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, frameworks

I've been a developer Unity iOS developer for a while now and I recently tried to test out my app on my phone. After building the project and uploading it to xCode so I can upload the app on my phone, the app was developed but crashes once I opened it. There are some warning logs but not sure which one is causing the crashing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKY8e.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4ryX.png

I also might think this is because I am not paying for the Apple developer program, yet before I was able to test it without paying for it.

Logs:

```
2020-03-28 14:11:21.207192-0700 TheSuccFinal[2733:973093] Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'

/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: stat() failed with errno=3
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'
```

2020-03-28 14:11:21.247919-0700 TheSuccFinal[2733:973093] Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework'

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8DD7379-FF01-4A00-AF26-77A546A87C8E/TheSuccFinal.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the Xcode runtime logs

Comment: Oh you can't see the logs? i added some pictures

Comment: Please add your crash log.

Comment: @BenedictT I mean the app runtime logs that appear when you run your app while connected to the IDE in debug mode

Comment: oh got it. I added them

Comment: This is related to the free account, see https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-crash.823998/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to iOS 13.3.1 since recent releases from Apple iOS builder, personal (non-developer) Apple accounts cannot sign frameworks correctly, since Unity is a framework itself it is not signed when built.

You can check [this unity forum discussion](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-crash.823998/) and [this discussion in the flutter framework](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504) about the bug.

Apparently it is fixed in iOS 13.4, so check your XCode version, iOS target version and you should be good to go.